# Is there a sequence of thought I can do to solve complex circuits using only KVL and KCL?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

[image]

This question took me a good 20-30mins of solving, and this just feels like a long time especially when I take my midterm exam it will only be 2 circuits in 1 hour only, so I need to make sure I find the right path quickly without finding out I did it wrong at the middle of the question.

So, is there are sequence of thought I can use to find the correct path to solve this question quickly, or rather, in the most efficient way without doing any unnecessary KVL or KCL?

Here's my solution (sorry for my bad writing):
[image: Page1]
[image: Page2]

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a few seconds to convert your schematic to this:

[image]

Most of the time was in making it "pretty" for here. I've cut off the bottom node because that will be assigned \$0\:\text{V}\$, arbitrarily. (Ground.) So don't need a wire there. I also chopped out your \$20\:\text{V}\$ source and cut its wires, replacing the wire ends with a known value. And I added an unknown current through the dependent voltage source.

Note that I've two independent nodes. So I'd use KCL.

Using Sympy/Python:

```
v1, v2, v3, ix = symbols( 'v1,v2,v3,ix', real=True )
e1 = Eq( v1/40 + v1/1 + v1/4, 20/1 + v2/4 )
e2 = Eq( v2/4 + v2/80 + 3.125*(20-v1) + ix, v1/4 )
e3 = Eq( v3/20 + v3/2, ix + 20/2 )
e4 = Eq( v3, v2 + 35*v1/40 )
solve( [ e1, e2, e3, e4 ], [ v1, v2, v3, ix ] )
{v1: 10.0000000000000,
 v2: -29.0000000000000,
 v3: -20.2500000000000,
 ix: -21.1375000000000}
```

From that it's easy to see that \$I_\varphi=\frac{10\:\text{V}}{40\:\Omega}=250\:\text{mA}\$, for example. And that the power delivered by the \$20\:\text{V}\$ source is \$\left(\frac{20\:\text{V}-\left[-20.25\:\text{V}\right]}{2\:\Omega}+\frac{20\:\text{V}-10\:\text{V}}{1\:\Omega}\right)\cdot 20\:\text{V}=602.5\:\text{W}\$.

I already had SymPy running so the clock time for all this, including typing here was 3.5 minutes. Just checked.

---

I haven't compared this with your writing (otherwise that would have increased the clocktime.) And I won't. I'll let you do that. But I'll go check my work using LTspice:

[image]

Took me more time here to get the behavioral formula typed in correctly and the two important values circled, than much of anything else.

---

Now that I'm doing some reading of your writing, I find you didn't get the answers laid out correctly, either. Oh, well. It's one thing to take a half hour to get correct answers. It's another if those answers are wrong, as well.

---

So the sequence for me was to first strip away the ground wire. Keeps my mind from thinking about it, as I don't want to do so. I remove known voltage sources tied to ground and replace their value-ends with their value. I also don't want to think about them or get confused by their presence. Then I assign node names and unknown currents. I also do a quick scan to see if currents or voltages can be expressed with known formulas (your varphi I, for example, can be replaced by its known formula.) I find known relationships between nodes. The image shows that work-product. Then I plug and go.

Comment: Note that including all the time it took to write, cross check, and perform operations using paint, as well as verifying and expanding and correcting my writing here, the whole process took me less than a half hour. But getting the right answers took less than four minutes and that included all of my annotation work before getting started.

Comment: So the sequence for me was to first strip away the ground wire. Keeps my mind from thinking about it, as I don't want to do so. I remove known voltage sources tied to ground and replace their value-ends with their value. I also don't want to think about them or get confused by their presence. Then I assign node names and unknown currents. I also do a quick scan to see if currents or voltages can be expressed with known formulas (your varphi I, for example, can be replaced by its known formula.) I find known relationships between nodes. The image shows that work-product. Then I plug and go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, all this is a little complicated as it's a new approach to solving this kind of question. for example, where will I do KVLs? how did you get the v3 above?

Comment: @AhmedSoliman Look on the right side of the first image. Do you see where I worked out the value of \$I_\varphi\$? You should immediately see where that came from. If you don't, then this is the first problem you have and you need to figure that out, first, in your mind. But if you agree there, then all you have to do is look at the dependent voltage source equation (it's right there in the schematic) to figure out how to then substitute the expression for \$I_\varphi\$ into that and get \$V_3\$. It's kind of obvious to me. I mean... very few seconds of time passed to see it, for me.

Comment: I see that Iφ went through 40Ω and consumed V1, so from ohm's law V=IR you get that Iφ = V1/40

Comment: @AhmedSoliman Excellent. That's a starting point, then. You should now see that the dependent voltage source must be 35 times that value. And if so, then \$V_3\$ must be \$V_2\$ plus that. Correct? These things should just snap in place, almost as fast as you can think words. In fact, faster than you can think in words. (I don't use words in my head. Just pictures and images. Stuff isn't bogged down by language in my head, I guess. Language slows things down too much. I see geometry, slopes, curves.)

Comment: Which 2 points does V3 take? I can't seem to understand where the V2 came from, why didn't we also add V1 for example? oh so we started from V2 and ended at V3, and along the way it went through the dependent voltage and either gained or lost that amount of voltage, which is equivalent to 35Iφ

Comment: @AhmedSoliman Hmm. Let's start at the beginning. You agree with \$I_\varphi\$. Let's use that as our foundation. We have \$V_2\$ as some kind of ***unknown***. We will solve for that, later. But it's a thing. Unknown thing. But a thing. Added to that is the dependent source. If we add the dependent source to \$V_2\$ then we get \$V_3\$ as a dependent result. Are we agreeing so far? \$V_2\$ isn't determined yet. Get that right! We don't know its value. That comes from analysis. But we simply assume that it has a value and that we can solve for it, later.

Comment: Yeah I agree with that

Comment: So. If \$I_\varphi=\frac{V_1}{40\:\Omega}\$ then it follows that the dependent voltage source must be \$35\:\Omega\cdot I_\varphi=35\:\Omega\cdot\frac{V_1}{40\:\Omega}\$. Are you with me so far? If so, then we can add that expression to \$V_2\$ to get \$V_3\$. Not so?

Comment: Yes I understand till now.

Comment: So it must be that \$V_3=V_2+35\:\Omega\cdot\frac{V_1}{40\:\Omega}\$. Still with me?

Comment: Yes, I'm still with you.

Comment: @AhmedSoliman So that is where you see, on the left top, that I write the same equation there. Do you see it? Do you also see where I specify that same equation in SymPy? (I very much want you to see things as I do. So I'm very happy to walk you through all this.)

Comment: Yes, In equation 4

Comment: @AhmedSoliman So. Where's the disconnect now? Everything is laid out in plain view.

Comment: What do you mean by disconnect? Yes I do understand till we got the V3. We basically started to get all the independent nodes at the beginning, so now we have V1, V2 and V3, but they're still unknowns.

Comment: @AhmedSoliman You should, given our agreements so far, have all your answers. You asked, *"I can't seem to understand where the V2 came from, why didn't we also add V1 for example?"* You should see that \$V_2\$ is an unknown to solve. It's a thing. But a thing we can solve for. You should also understand that \$V_1\$ is yet another unknown to solve for. It's included in the expression for \$V_3\$. But we don't know its value yet. But we also don't need to know its value yet. So \$V_1\$ is another unknown to work out. What's left to worry over?

Comment: what's left is to get those unknowns.

Comment: @AhmedSoliman Yes! We leave those two as unknowns. They will get resolved. Don't worry about that. But we don't need to know their values, a priori, either. We leave that to the analysis results.

Comment: So now we use KVL and KCL and we should be done?

Comment: @AhmedSoliman  Well, KCL for the nodes. Then KVL for the relationship between \$V_2\$ and \$V_3\$. So both are being applied, granted. In directed graph theory, there are two nullspaces. One of the nullspaces represents KCL. The other nullspace represents KVL. So in a larger context both KCL and KVL are always in play, simultaneously. But that's a whole other topic of discussion that pulls in applied mathematics.

Comment: for KVL, must it be a relationship between V2 and V3 only or will it have more unknowns? which loop should I use for KVL?

Comment: @AhmedSoliman It's not necessary to form a loop for KVL. It's enough to, sometimes, just add one voltage to another. That doesn't mean you cannot form the complete loop. I don't want you to think that. But you can short-cut the the process if you want to. That's what I did. Still, feel free to make a loop.

Comment: KVL isn't all about loops only?

Comment: The thing is, my exam will not be MCQ and I must be solving the questions like how I showed it in the post, basically I must be forming loops.

Comment: @AhmedSoliman No. You can form a loop. And you can go there if you want to. But it is also can be about just adding one voltage to another.

Comment: So we're done with KVL now once we finally got V3, now the rest should be KCLs, correct?

Comment: @AhmedSoliman Well,  the details of what you must demonstrate in your writing is yet another thing. I don't care about that. That's for you to solve with respect to your class requirements. But you can use my advice, plus your own knowledge about your class requirements, to get to where you need to me. Logic and the application of correct axioms result in sound reasoning. And it doesn't matter which you make as axioms and which you make as logic. The result will be the same, if applied well.

Comment: @AhmedSoliman You can see from my work product which is KCL and which is KVL. You just need to move quickly, mentally. That's all. Be fluent and fascicle of thought.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand it all now, this really opened my mind on how to look on the question, it can help me get the results quick or revise the question to make sure if I'm correct or not. Thank you so much for taking your time explaining that to me.

Comment: @AhmedSoliman I really want, very much, for you to follow along. It means a lot to me. I very much appreciate your willingness to follow along with me. And thanks for that. This is important. For me to pass along what is in my head to others. It matters to me. Best wishes. And I mean that with very ounce of my soul and heart. If you gather up just some of this in your mind I will be very grateful for even just that much.